# Extract HTML content from GWT page

Tags: html, gwt, html-parsing, jericho-html-parser

I want to parse the content of an HTML page written in GWT. I tried it to parse it using Jericho HTML content parser but the problem is that the page source does not have content. After doing some research on GWT pages, i came to know that GWT pages are written in JAVA and GWT compiler creates a complex structure of js pages from java code to display the HTML content on browser.

is there a way i can parse these type of pages?

Answer (score 1):

If the code is compiled in `OBF - Obfuscated mode` (code is usually compiled in this mode for production use) it will be VERY difficult, as `JS` files created are non-human readable.

This [link](http://css.dzone.com/news/understanding-gwt-compiler) might be helpful to make you understand GWT Compiler better.

**EDIT**:

[Here you go](http://blog.gdssecurity.com/labs/tag/gwt). This might also be helpful. It is mentioned here how to `De-obfuscate the Javascript`.

**EDIT2**:

[GWT-Penetration-Testing-Toolset](https://github.com/GDSSecurity/GWT-Penetration-Testing-Toolset) - Check this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Just like with (m)any "single-page web app" (including e.g. Twitter, which is *not* built with GWT), you have to run the JavaScript code and then scrape the DOM.

This can be *easily* (everything's relative) done using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or similar tools.

Comment: GWT Compiles the code in non-human readable form. How to tackle that?

Comment: There is no problem in parsing pages which are not built in GWT. as @HashimR mentioned: GWT compiles the code in non-human readable form.. Is there a way i can detect it is GWT page or a normal web page?

Comment: There are many other "compilers" that obfuscate JS code (UglifyJS, Closure Compiler, YUI Compressor, etc.), GWT is no different. And as I said: don't try to read in the code, just run it!

Comment: Here's an example that is *not* built with GWT: https://twitter.com/#!/opera/status/195796939709743105

Comment: Whatever is written in Java in the server side, that is eventually converted to HTML/CSS/Javascript in the browser environment so that it can render the page. So how come the source code remains blank?

Comment: And by the way, Firebug shows the source code in a complex layout of tables. How come doing a `CTRL-U` shows an empty body element?

Comment: Page is empty + script → script runs and populates the DOM → Firebug shows the populated DOM. So, you need to run the JS code and then scrape the DOM, case made.